# Multiple integers one line without using array?

Tags: java.util.scanner

Hey guys i'm not sure if the answer is out there, I don't quite know how to describe the question I have. I've looked on here for about 45 minutes and couldn't find much that answered my question. So I apologize if it has already been posted elsewhere.

I need to be able to take a series of numbers inputted on a single line and take numbers that are only 6 - 10, and find the average and maximum of the numbers between 6 - 10.

Example : 4 5 6 6 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 9 9 9
and : 8 6 3 10

Problem is that I've found answers if you are looking to receive X amount of inputs, but the assignment I'm working on is going to input anywhere from like 1 - 20 numbers on a single line.

I cannot use Array for my assignment, I wish I could since it would make things much easier. I am completely lost as what to do.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Are you looking help for the use of a scanner of you didn't get the way you should do the average on a unknown amount of numbers?
In the second case you have to check for the number to be in the range (6-10), keep a counter to know how many numbers you processed and finally sum the numbers and divide by the counter.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is a String with a space as delimeter you could do something like this

```
String string = "4 5 6 6 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 9 9 9";
List<String> splittedStrings = Arrays.asList(string.split(" "));
```

After that you have a List with the splitted input that you can process in any way you imagine (like removing unwanted entries und summing them up).

**Update:**

Something like this should work even without an array or list:

```
    String string = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20";
    string = string.replaceAll("16|17|17|18|19|20|[1-5](?!0)", "").trim();
    System.out.println(string);
    int counter = 0;
    int value = 0;
    int max = 0;
    while (!string.isEmpty()) {
        String substring = "";
        if (string.indexOf(" ") == -1) {
            substring = string;
            string = "";
        } else {
            substring = string.substring(0, string.indexOf(" "));
            string = string.substring(string.indexOf(" ")).trim();
        }
        if (!substring.isEmpty()) {
            int integer = Integer.valueOf(substring).intValue();
            if (integer > max) {
                max = integer;
            }
            value = value + integer;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Max: " + max + "; Average: " + Double.valueOf(value) / counter);
```

Comment: I can't use an Array unfortunately. All the answers on here use an Array but the instructor will give us a failing grade if you use something he hasn't discussed.

Comment: i posted an alternative with regex